# Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mapping, automapper

I am getting Missing type map configuration error when I call `Mapper.Map(object,object);`
Here is my current setup.

Global.asax.cs - Calling

```
 AutoMapperAppSvcConfiguration.Configure();
```

Configuration.cs -

```
 Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
            {
           cfg.AddProfile(new ExportProfile());
             });

  public class ExportProfile : Profile
    {
        protected override void Configure()
        {
             Mapper.CreateMap<JobDTO,JobSpec>();
        }
```

Import Task file:

```
var JobDTOSpec = new class JobDTO();
    // Fill in JobDTOSpec object with appropriate fields.
    JobDTOSpec.property1 = "hello";

..... more properties.
// JobDTO and JobSpec class are identical as well.

  var JobSpec = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map(JobDTO, new JobSpec()); <-- Error  occurs.
```

This error does not occur on each task job(WCF Service call). We are currently running 100's of task job. Mapping works fine for first 30 minutes or so. After that we started getting Mapping configuration error.
My Question is : Is there any way Automapper would loose itss memory because server(iis) is being overloaded of thousands of jobs and forgets mapping.(we were hitting our WCF service around 2GB memory on IIS). Is there any limit after certain calls Mapping would reset it's mapping memory and in a mean time if server gets call would it not recognize/remember mapping types?. What else could cause this error with memory issue or under heavy server load.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you call base.CreateMap, not Mapper.CreateMap in your Profile class.

Comment: I will give it a try. Could you please tell me a difference between those too?

Comment: CreateMap associates the map configuration with the profile. More importantly, there is some locking going on around profiles that when you do Mapper.CreateMap, it's not thread-safe any more.